NestJS reinitialise a provider
I have a self published npm package that contains an api call to a token endpoint and also a cron job that runs every 30 minutes to refresh the token.
I import this into my BFF projects and use it like this in a client provider:
import { TokenService } from '@MYIMPORTEDCOMMONMODULE;
import { ApiClient } from './api;

export const apiClientProvider = {
  provide: 'ApiClient',
  useFactory: async (tokenService: TokenService) => {

    const token = await tokenService.getToken();
    console.log('Initial token:', token);

    const apiConfig = {
      BASE: process.env.NX_API_BASE_ENDPOINT || 'http://localhost:9096',
      HEADERS: {
        Authorization: token 
      }
    };

    return new ApiClient(apiConfig);
  },
  inject: [TokenService],
};

Because this is initialised at startup the token is retrieved and set the first time but then when it expires 30 minutes later I need to reinitialise it again so that it picks up the new token. Is what I’m trying to do possible? Open to suggestions to different ways to achieve the desired outcome but would prefer the bulk of the code to be in the npm package so I don’t have to update multiple projects. Thanks.

Why not just make this a simple service that has a refreshToken() method, that makes the call and sets this.token = newToken. Nest JS services are singletons, so that should make the new token available everywhere that needs it with no fuss.

Thanks for you response. Taken me a while to get back to this. Doesn't the provider only initialise the once? At startup. So I'm not sure I can do what you are suggesting with a provider like this. I've been looking at a Subject set as an observable that updates when the Cron Job updates but I'm still not sure if the provider will update after initialisation.

As I needed to refresh the token every 30 mins I just did it inside of the provider rather than in the token service itself making it much simpler.
import { TokenService } from '@MYIMPORTEDCOMMONMODULE;
import { ApiClient } from './api;
export const apiClientProvider = {
provide: 'ApiClient',
useFactory: async (tokenService: TokenService) => {
let token = 'DummyProviderToken'
const apiConfig = {
  BASE: process.env.NX_API_BASE_ENDPOINT || 'http://localhost:9096',
  HEADERS: {
    Authorization: token 
  }
};

const userClient = new UserClient(apiConfig);
const updateToken = async () => {
    if (process.env.NX_TIBCO_TOKEN_RETRIEVAL === 'true') {
      token = await tokenService.getToken();
    } else {
        token = randomBytes(8).toString('hex');
    }
      console.log('Token updated', token);
      userClient.request.config.TOKEN = token;
    };

  // Update token every 30 minutes (1800000 milliseconds)
  // Update token every 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds)

  setInterval(updateToken, 30000);

  await updateToken();

  return userClient;
},
inject: [TokenService],
};

